# loop de numeros, retirando alguns que ja foi usado

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, Estou com dificuldade em resolver um código aqui eu tenho a seguinte tabela no banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O campo "**total**" é o total de números que a rifa tem

O campo "**num_pago**" são os números que ja foram vendidos.

Quero mostrar os números em até 150 que é  quantidade de números que a rifa tem, mais quero que os números 5,8,9 apareçam em vermelho!! que o usuário não vai conseguir clicar... Pensando isso eu criei o seguinte código!

```
for($i = 1; $i < 150 $i++)
{
  if( in_array($i, array(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) ) ){
    continue;
  }
  echo "<li><a class='desativado' href='#'><i>$i</i></a></li>";
}
```

O Codigo acima funciona, ele nao aparece os numeros 1,3,4,5,6,7 etc.. mais quando eu coloco o valor do db   assim:

`if( in_array($i, array($dados['total']) ) ){`

ele não mostra os outros numero, ele só retira o numero '1' o restante continua aparecendo.
e falta eles 'não' aparecem também!!

quando eu pego o valor do banco de dados ele buga nao sei oque acontece
simplesmente ele continua mostrando os outros numeros

Queria que ficasse assim:

Alguem pode me ajudar, estou parado nisso desde ontem!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O q vc está fazendo é testar se o número está em [150] e não em [1, 2, ... 150].  A melhor lógica é testar se o número já foi sorteado e usar um “senão “

Comment: oi castro bom dia, eu nao entendi muito bem nao! consegue me explicar melhor?

Comment: O Bernardo fez justamente o q eu sugeri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse é o resultado que vem do seu banco de dados:

```
$dados['total'] = 150
$dados['num_pagos'] = '5,8,9'
```

Você tem que trocar `$dados['total']` por `$dados['num_pagos']` e pode colocar um `else` também:

```
$num_pagos = explode(',', $dados['num_pago']);
for($i = 1; $i <= $dados['total']; $i++)
{
  if (in_array($i, $nums_pagos) ){
    echo "<li><a class='desativado' href='#'><i>$i</i></a></li>";
  } else {
    echo "<li><a class='ativado' href='#'><i>$i</i></a></li>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ele funciona só com resultado colocado na mão, quando pega do db ele só funciona com o primeiro numero!

Comment: È realmente eu fiz um teste e funciona só com o primeiro numero com resultados vindo do DB.. porque sera? estou em busca da mesma coisa!

Comment: essa parte ->   if (in_array($i, array($dados['num_pagos']) ) ){    

se pegar e colocar na mão ele funciona, se colocar vindo do DB ele pega só o primeiro numero!! me ajuda!

Comment: Não funciona porque o $dados['num_pagos'] é string, e não array. Eu atualizei a resposta transformando $dados['num_pagos'] em array e depois fazendo a verificação.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver [@Wallace Maxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters) Obrigado!!!

> Vi que você já fez uma pergunta parecida aqui no site. Caso um código
> parecido, você teria que mudar a linha do seu in_array para
> in_array($i, explode(',', $dados['num_pago']))

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]